# Elasticsearch plugin to build and execute search template query

Tags: elasticsearch-plugin

I'm creating an Elasticsearch plugin, where I want to build a template query as an inline text string and execute it.

For that using mustache `SearchTemplateRequestBuilder` for Elasticsearch 6.1.2 and getting response by this code:

```
   SearchResponse sr = new SearchTemplateRequestBuilder(nodeClient)
                    .setScript("{\n" +
                            "        \"query\" : {\n" +
                            "            \"match\" : {\n" +
                            "                \"gender\" : \"{{param_gender}}\"\n" +
                            "            }\n" +
                            "        }\n" +
                            "}")
                    .setScriptType(ScriptType.INLINE)
                    .setScriptParams(template_params)
                    .setRequest(new SearchRequest())
                    .get()
                    .getResponse();
```

This is an example from their documentation.

I've found a problem with this exception:

```
"class_cast_exception", 
"reason": "org.elasticsearch.script.mustache.SearchTemplateRequest cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.script.mustache.SearchTemplateRequest"
```

So, is there a solution for what I'm trying to implement? And how can I avoid the exception?